# Product Tax Rate Calculation

Tags: tax

Example:

I have a product including price is RS 1750 (inr) and tax rate is 5.5%.

And my shopping CART is showing like this

---

```
SUBTOTAL    RS 1,658.77
TAX         RS 91.23

GRAND TOTAL RS 1,750.00
```

---

But 5.5% of 1750 is 96.25

[image]

So what is the wrong?

Comment: Tax will be calculated for SUBTOTAL and it did right in  case of you `(1658.77*5.5)/100=91.23` `1658.77+91.23=1750`

Comment: That is correct, Can you please explain how magento calculated/got 1658.77 as subtotal?

Comment: Subtotal is the price of products in the cart what your error actually are you getting subtotal wrong??

Comment: I updated my question with image, How magento getting subtotal as 1658.77 from 1750 and tax rate is 5.5%. according my calculation the subtotal would be 1653.75 from 5.5% of 1750

Answer (score 0):

you can edit some setting as you need in your cart

```
System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Shopping Cart Display Settings
```

Display Subtotal    Store View  Determines whether the shopping cart subtotal is shown with tax, without tax, or both.

**Excluding Tax:** Shopping cart subtotal does not include tax.

**Including Tax:** Shopping cart subtotal includes tax.

**Including and Excluding Tax:** Shopping cart subtotal is displayed with and without tax.

you can also refer [doc here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuration-sales-tax-shopping-cart-display-settings)

hope this will sure help you